# Combination issue

Tags: probability

I understand almost all parts of this problem. The thing I *don't* get is where the 5 comes from in the combination set-up (same for 6 in the next part). Why isn't it 7 choose 3 in Pr(x=7) , vice versa ?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it this way: *The losing team can't win the last game*. So if you want the series to go six games you have to have the losing team lose their two games within the first five games, *not* within six games. Same for if the series goes for five games or seven games.

Answer (score 4):

The teams compete ***until*** one team wins four games.

$\mathsf P(X=4)$ is the probability that one team won their forth game on game four.   This is the event of winning all in the first three games then the next game.  $$\mathsf P(X=4) = 2(0.5)^4$$

$\mathsf P(X=5)$ is the probability that one team won their forth game on game five.   This is the event of winning three games in the first four, then the next game.  $$\mathsf P(X=5) = 2\binom{4}{3}(0.5)^5\\ \qquad\qquad = 2\binom{4}{1}(0.5)^5$$

$\mathsf P(X=6)$ is the probability that one team won their forth game on game six.   This is the event of winning three games in the first five, then the next game.  $$\mathsf P(X=6) = 2\binom{5}{3}(0.5)^6\\ \qquad\qquad = 2\binom{5}{2}(0.5)^6$$

$\mathsf P(X=7)$ is the probability that one team won their forth game on game 
seven.   This is the event of winning three games in the first six, then the next game.  $$\mathsf P(X=7) = 2\binom{6}{3}(0.5)^7$$

$\mathsf P(X=8)$ is the probability that one team won their forth game on game eight.   This is the event cannot happen because someone must win four games earlier than that.  $$\mathsf P(X=8) = 0$$

Comment: In describing $P(X = 4)$, you meant to say that $P(X = 4)$ is the probability that one team won their fourth game in game *four*.

Comment: Yes.  Cut and pasta error.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the teams are $A,B$, with respectively probabilities of winning of $p, q (=1-p)$.

**Assume tournament ends after $n$ games**.

If $A$ wins the tournament, then $A$ has to win $k-1$ games in the first $n-1$ games, and also win the last game. Probability of this happening is 
$$\binom {n-1}{k-1}p^{k-1}q^{n-k}p=\binom {n-1}{k-1}p^kq^{n-k}=\binom{n-1}3(0.5)^n$$
as $k=4, p=q=0.5$.

Similarly, if B wins the tournament, probability is

$$\binom {n-1}{k-1}q^kp^{n-k}=\binom{n-1}3(0.5)^n$$

Combining both gives probability of tournament ending in $n$ games (with either $A$ or $B$ winning), i.e. 
$$p(n)=2\binom{n-1}3(0.5)^n$$

**Now consider all possible values of $n$** (i.e. $4$ to $7$).

Expected number of games is given by 
$$\sum_{n=4}^7 n\cdot \underbrace{2\binom{n-1}3(0.5)^n}_{p(n)}=2\left[4\binom 33(0.5)^4+5\binom 43(0.5)^5+6\binom 53(0.5)^6+7\binom 63(0.5)^7\right]\qquad\blacksquare$$